# How do you pronounce the "ng" in "language" and "English"?

Tags: pronunciation, world-english

I'm hearing more and more people pronounce "language" as [laŋ-wij] instead of [laŋ-gwij]. The same goes for the word "English": [iŋ-lish] instead of [iŋ-glish].

How prevalent has this pronunciation become in the "inner circle" of English speakers? How do you pronounce these words?

Comment: Yes, we still do pronounce the *g* in both the words. If some don't, nothing official about it.

Comment: The variant pronunciation's already been entered in Merriam Webster, which implies that it's being used by educated speakers (in America, at least).  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/language

Comment: I have a feeling I may just switch randomly between the two. In careful speech, I'm sure I'd pronounce the g, but in rapid speech, I don't doubt I'd easily drop it sometimes.

Comment: @virtualxtc - AmE here, have never heard them pronounced that way North or South nor even in Texas. What makes you say that? I'm very curious. (btw, it's *states*. You can correct me on my frequent *it's* for its.) Are you sure it's not a Boston thing? (see Peter Shor)

Comment: @Susan: If I do it, it's probably either a New York area or a California thing; these are where most of my accent comes from. But I also think it's something you wouldn't hear unless you were listening for it. The people who do it on [forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com/word/language/#en) seem to be from the South, from New York, and from Australia.

Comment: For example, listen to this guy from England. He pronounces the "g" in "English" but not in "language". @PeterShor https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W32TMpeLSW8

Comment: @Louel - You're right. I've never heard that before! Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Susan Yet, oddly enough, the variant pronunciation isn't entered in OED. It's entered in Merriam-Webster, but it seems not many Americans are familiar with it.

Comment: In Britain a middle or final consonant is pronounced far more heavily in the north than in the south, where it can be replaced with a glottal stop. (London and Home Counties) But in the north a word like 'ringing' is pronounced almost as if it had a double g in the middle.- 'ringging'. My young grandson who is at primary school in Manchester will say 'The telephone is rinGGinG' or 'Please will you help me with my lanGuage and literacy homework'.

Comment: @Susan perhaps my perception based on skits I've seen rather than first hand experience

Comment: If you ask how to pronounce *longitude* you will find a US/UK difference.

Answer (score 3):

I've personally never heard the mispronunciations to which you are referring.
I always hear the 'g' in both those words in everyday conversations.

Unfortunately, I also hear the 't' in 'often' FAR too often… ;-)

Comment: Though pronouncing the "t" isn't wrong, is it? At least Oxford doesn't think so.

Comment: @Louel: They don't think so because so many people are doing it nowadays. Some of us can remember the days when pronouncing the "t" was wrong.

Comment: Strangely enough, I thought it was very "British" to pronounce the "t" (maybe because I don't pronounce the "t"). I thought it was the standard pronunciation in the past.

Comment: @Louel: I am fairly sure the standard pronunciation of *often* in the 19th century was without the 't': the 1892 Webster's International Dictionary (searchable on Google books) only gives that pronunciation, as does John Walker's 1827 Pronouncing Dictionary (published in London, also searchable on Google books). I don't know how the 't' got reintroduced (it must have been there in the 16th century, as otherwise it wouldn't be in the spelling).

Comment: There's always been a "t" as the root word is "oft". http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060706193650AAmjRiw

Comment: Yes, but the 't' is/was silent.  My favorite lexicomane, Charles Harrington Elster, is quoted on a page devoted to this very subject: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/how-do-you-pronounce-often .  Here's an excerpt:
**"… analogy is entirely unsupportive: no one pronounces the t in soften, listen, fasten, moisten, hasten, chasten, christen, and Christmas—so, once and for all, let’s do away with the eccentric AWF-tin."**

Answer (score 1):

I might have heard the /g/ dropped in 'language' once or twice, but don't think I've ever heard it dropped in 'English' (even by Finns, whose corresponding word 'englanti' lacks the /g/ sound).

For me, both certainly do have the /g/ sound in them. /ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒ/ and /ˈɪŋɡlɪʃ/ respectively.  As far as I know, everybody I know pronounces them them the same.

Answer (score -3):

The only times I have heard the words used with a dropped "g" have been on television soaps which are frequented by glottal stops and lazy pronunciation. At all other times the hard "g" has been pronounced.
In the case of the extension to the answer,I have never heard often with a pronounced t. I often hear it as: offd'n or off'n.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.